# Probability generating function question about property

Tags: probability

When $S=X_1+X_2, G_S(t)=G_{X_1}(t)G_{X_2}(t)$. However, when $S=X_1-X_2, G_S(t)=G_{X_1}(t)G_{X_2}(\frac{1}{t})$ instead of $G_S(t)=\frac{G_{X_1}(t)}{G_{X_2}(t)}$. Why is this so? (assuming independent trials of $X$)

Comment: For this you need to assume independence! Please edit that is (if that is your intention)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a ratio of *Probability Generating Function*, because $\mathsf E(t^{-X_2})\neq \mathsf E(t^{X_2})^{-1}$

Indeed, what it is, and why it is so, is:

$\mathsf G_{X_1-X_2}(t) ~{~=~ \mathsf E(t^{(X_1-X_2)})\\ ~=~ \mathsf E(t^{X_1})\,\mathsf E(t^{-X_2})\qquad\text{since, independent} \\~=~\mathsf G_{X_1}(t)\,\mathsf G_{X_2}(1/t)}$

Comment: Then $G_{X_1}(t)G_{X_2}(\frac{1}{t})=G_{X_1}(t)G_{X_2}(-t)$? Thank you very much by the way.